# Fectching data in oracle table which has common value in other column in same table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table which looks as follows;

```
Column A      Column B         Column C
---------     ---------        --------
  GBR            UK1              177
  GBR            UK2              177
  GBR            UK2              178
  GBR            UK3              178
  GBR            UK1              178
  GBR            UK4              177
  GBR            UK5              179
  GBR            UK6              180
  GBR            UK2              179
  GBR            UK1              179
  GBR            UK2              180
  GBR            UK1              180
```

Now I need a query in Oracle that should give me only those values of Column B which have all values of Column C in common (here 177, 178,179,180). The answer here is obviously UK1 and UK2 but how to get a query for this? Thanks

Comment: Is `(columnB, columnC)` a unique composite key or can you have more than one instance of a value in `columnC` for a given value in `columnB`?

Comment: Can you clarify whether you are looking for Column B values that have *all possible* values of column C, or only those matching the set of values for another Column B value? For instance, if a record `GBR  UK6  181` was added to the dataset, would it affect the rows returned?

Comment: @APC: Col B and Col C is not composite key... can have more than one instance.

Comment: @MarkBannister: Only those values in Col B which have all values (total 4 here, not any less) of Col C.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Please try:

```
select ColumnA, ColumnB From YourTable
where ColumnC in (177, 178, 179, 180)
group by ColumnA, ColumnB
having count(distinct ColumnC)=4
```

Comment: -1 The problems with this query are: (a) it's doing a select on the values of `ColumnC`, despite the fact that the OP said he wanted to match *all* values of `ColumnC` (so at best this step is useless, at worst - if more values are added to `ColumnC` - it will give the wrong output), (b) the `having count(*)` condition is hardcoded to 4 (which will work only as long as there are exactly 4 values in `ColumnC`), and (c) the inner query `select distinct * from YourTable` is unnecessary (the `having` condition could be on `having count(distinct ColumnC)`) leading to unnecessary processing.

Comment: OK, the unnecessary inner select is gone, but the query is still explicitly selecting ColumnC values *and* using a hard-coded value in the having clause.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a query similar to the following:

```
select ColumnB
from yt
group by ColumnB
having count(distinct ColumnC) = (select count(distinct ColumnC)
                                  from yt);
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/88ec1/3)

Comment: @MarkBannister: Only those values in Col B which have all values (total 4 here, not any less) of Col C